# How do I access nested information in a JSON API response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, axios

I am trying to build a simple CLI cryptocurrency tracker app. The application performs a successful API call and returns the following response:

```
[ { exchange: 'binance',
    base: 'ADA',
    quote: 'BTC',
    price_quote: '0.00001663',
    timestamp: '2019-04-08T16:36:00Z' },
  { exchange: 'binance',
    base: 'ADX',
    quote: 'BTC',
    price_quote: '0.00003316',
    timestamp: '2019-04-08T16:35:00Z' },
...]
```

How do I access a specific object within the response? For example, how could I return the entire object where `base: 'ADA`?

Here is the simple Axios call that returns the JSON response:

```
axios.get("https://api.nomics.com/v1/exchange-markets/prices?key=" + apiKey + "&currency=BTC&exchange=binance")
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data)
    })
```

Comment: example `arr.find(obj => obj.base = 'ADA')`

Comment: You access nested data just like you would on a normal JS object, simply because the API response, once processed by axios, is a normal JS object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
let response = [ { exchange: 'binance',base: 'ADA',quote: 'BTC',price_quote: '0.00001663',timestamp: '2019-04-08T16:36:00Z' },
{exchange: 'binance', base: 'ADX',quote: 'BTC',price_quote: '0.00003316',timestamp: '2019-04-08T16:35:00Z' },]

let value = response.find(e => e.base === 'ADA')

console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.get("https://api.nomics.com/v1/exchange-markets/prices?key=" + apiKey + "&currency=BTC&exchange=binance")
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data.find(data=>data.base==='ADA'))
}
```

The “find” function will go through every item of the array until it finds the item matches the provided boolean condition and returns it.

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this 
code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)